# NUM_ROWS problems will not write anything out at all

Tags: php, mysqli

hey this is how I must have made ​​such that if the database can not find anything that matches the database or can find anything then it should come forward and say something, but I'm totally resolve around how to build it at. I will hear about in could help me

I try to do this:

```
<?php
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT id_forum, title, tekst, dato, id_brugere FROM `forum` ORDER BY `forum`.`id` DESC'))
{
   $stmt->execute();
   $stmt->bind_result($id, $djnavn, $profilbillede);
   $rows = $stmt->num_rows;
   echo $rows;

   while ($stmt->fetch())
   {
   ?>
      <td class="titleforum"></td>
      <td>Dato:</td>
   <?php
   }
   $stmt->close();
}
else
   $row_cnt = $result->num_rows;
   print_r($row_cnt);
?>
```

but it does not appear anything anything at all talk or look like .. what I want out of this is that it says something?

Comment: Learn how to accept answers, or no-one'll be interested in helping you out.

Comment: yes ok but I am very now and do not know how to do it?

Comment: @JesperPetersen Start reading the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). Accept answers by visiting your old questions and click the tick to the left of the answer that solved your problem.

Comment: So you mean check? and can you provide a link to where I can find all my posts?

Comment: @JesperPetersen In the top of this webpage, you will see your name. Click your name to access your profile and posts.

Comment: Link: http://stackoverflow.com/users/1205141/jesper-petersen?tab=questions

Comment: it has been better? and, it is okay :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
<?php
if ($stmt = $mysqli -> prepare('SELECT id_forum, title, tekst, dato, id_brugere FROM `forum` ORDER BY `forum`.`id` DESC'))
{
   $stmt -> execute();
   $stmt -> store_result();

   $rows = $stmt -> num_rows;
   echo $rows;

   while ($stmt -> fetch()) {
?>
      <td class="titleforum"></td>
      <td>Dato:</td>
   <?php
   }
   $stmt->close();
}
?>
```

See: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.num-rows.php

Comment: It does not come forward and say anything at all hmmm